# SSO - Bimonthly and monthly (Thailand)

Tags: payroll, thailand

The concern is related to SSO Amount in Monthly Payroll.

Please confirm which one is correct as per Payroll Regulation in the 2 scenarios and please share the Evidence if possible.

Scenario 1 :

- For the 1st Bi-Monthly payroll in May 2023, the SSO amount is calculated as 5% of the Basic Salary, resulting in 136.50 THB (rounded to 137 THB).
- For the Monthly payroll in May 2023, the SSO amount is calculated as 5% of the Basic Salary, resulting in 508.88 THB (rounded to 509 THB).
- Customer Comment: The customer indicates that the SSO amount for the Monthly payroll is not correct, as the first bi-monthly payroll was processed before the monthly payroll.

Scenario 2 :

- For the 1st Bi-Monthly payroll in May 2023, the SSO amount is calculated as 5% of the Basic Salary, resulting in 136.50 THB (rounded to 137 THB).
- For the Monthly payroll in May 2023, the SSO amount is calculated differently. It is computed as 5% of the sum of the Monthly Basic Salary (10,177.50 THB) and the Basic Salary from the 1st Bi-Monthly payroll (2,730.00 THB), minus the SSO amount already deducted from the 1st Bi-Monthly payroll (137 THB). This results in 508.38 THB (rounded to 508 THB).
- Customer Comment: The customer indicates that this calculation matches their expectation, as the first bi-monthly payroll was processed before the monthly payroll.

So please confirm which approach is correct as per the regulations.

Comment: Homework assignment?

Comment: I'd say almost certainly homework.